# How to write unit tests for automation scripts?

Tags: unit-testing

I write a lot of ETL scripts that run however often to extract and update data.  I have written unit-tests for a lot of my commonly used utilities, but I am struggling to figure out how to write effective unit tests for the entire script due to the fact that if it fails or returns incorrect data I know about it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would follow these steps from https://smartbear.com/learn/automated-testing/best-practices-for-automation/

1. Decide what Test Cases to Automate
2. Test Early and Test Often
3. Select the Right Automated Testing Tool
4. Divide your Automated Testing Efforts
5. Create Good, Quality Test Data
6. Create Automated Tests that are Resistant to Changes in the UI